# YouTube Embed player in Iframe doesn't work in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview, youtube-api

I really need your help. Working on an iOS app. I want to play youtube. I understood from reading many many blogs and posts, that we need to use an iframe in order to play a youtube video.

However, on some videos I get: "**This video contains content from XYZ. It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube**"

I read this question: [Youtube in iOS5 - done button Tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761100/youtube-in-ios5-done-button-tapped/12860616#12860616) which gives the link to youtube api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
They recommend to use the iframe. 
the example for youtube site is:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"/>
```

The code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe webkit-playsinline id="player" type="text/html" width="320" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rEevIL1Wpcg?enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me understand it? I check the embedded flag to be true, they are all clips that are allowed to play on mobile devices.

Example for videos that works on the device:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEevIL1Wpcg&feature=youtube_gdata
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzGe7pbGUiM

Example for videos that **don't work** on the device and bring up the error msg:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vhFnTjia_I&feature=youtube_gdata
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxkiA0IjBZ0&feature=youtube_gdata

Comment: see high voted an answer at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) and if you running on simulator? then can be debug on Safari.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use webview as youtube player

**Try Below Code** it is working for me

in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;
```

and in your .m file

```
    NSString *videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com";

// if your url is not in embed format or it is dynamic then you have to convert it in embed format.

    videoURL = [videoURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"watch?v=" withString:@"embed/"];

    NSRange range = [videoURLString rangeOfString:@"&"];
    @try {
         videoURLString = [videoURLString substringToIndex:range.location];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }

    // here your link is converted in embed format.

    NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
    body {\
        background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
    </body></html>",videoURL];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Here you can change **webview frame** as you want and also can change **videoUrl**.

Comment: Although it didn't solve my problem. You are the one getting the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

There are two concepts, embeddable and syndicated.
iOS devices use iframe so they basically embed. 
Android devices that use player API can check syndicated.

When you do a [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), you can set [videoEmbeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoEmbeddable) and [videoSyndicated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated) to true.

Or if you are iterating through videos, for each video, you can do a [video->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with video id and check [status.embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) in the response.

Here is a [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html) about this topic, even though examples are in v2, information is still relevant.