# Youtube Playlist in iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, youtube

I'm wondering wether its possible to play a youtube playlist in an IOS App. i've been struggling to find an answer for this for some time now. i've tried several html5 players, but they do not support youtube playlists. Other than that i've tried using this simple code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:array[selectedRowValue]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

But this will only play the playlist and you wont be able to navigate between the playlist videos.

my question is then is there an API or any kind of sample codes easy to use for this purpose?

i'm thinking about something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try implementing a UIWebView into the tableview's header view and have the url change whenever a user selects a specific cell.

You can find the youtube player webview sample in the answer here [YouTube Embed player in Iframe doesn't work in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339575/youtube-embed-player-in-iframe-doesnt-work-in-ios6)