# Unable to play youtube video on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube

I am using `YTPlayerView` to play a YouTube video on iOS.

However, I get the error message seen below for some videos and am unable to play them on an iPhone.

*This video contains content from Panorama. It is restricted from playback on certain sites*

[image]

What can be the possible issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed Youtube videos :- with contains content from \* , it is restricted from playback on certain site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430337/embed-youtube-videos-with-contains-content-from-it-is-restricted-from-pl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. All i had to do is to enable *Allow embedding* in Distribution Option in Advance settings of video.

[image]