# How to Embed Youtube Video Code ( No Embed Option )

Tags: video, youtube

I have a new news website which is going to rely quite a lot on embedding Youtube videos, but I've just been onto Youtube and it seems that they have changed everything again.

I now see the share button to the bottom right hand side of the video, but when it is clicked, there is no `Embed` option. What's the deal with this?

Here is a photo of what I mean:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yRob.png)

Are YouTube getting rid if the Embedded Share option???

Answer (score 1):

I always right click on the video itself and get embed code from there ,its the same thing

Comment: This is a great way of getting the embed code, which I actually didn't know about. Thanks Joe!!!

Answer (score 0):

The person uploading the video can enable or disable embedding - it may be that this one had embedding disabled. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32211526/334402

Either way the video in your picture above appears to allow embedding now (tested on Safari on Mac):

[image]

Comment: My first thought was that it had been disabled, but it usually tells you, and after trying this on several different videos, I concluded that it wasn't anything to do with it being switched off. Also, **please note** that the screenshot you have uploaded shows the old (classic) Youtube, where I'm using the new version, which is why I wondered if they were planning on getting rid of the embed option.

Comment: @WD - can I check what you mean by the new version of YouTube - do you have a URL for a new version or are you using the YouTube app maybe?

Comment: All I know is that the page layout is different, and at the bottom left hand corner there is a small icon which when you hover over says "Restore Classic YouTube". I know that is a solution, but I wonder how long until they make these changes permanent